# on premise service bus windows security

Tags: security, servicebus

My client has an 'On Premise' Microsoft service bus currently secured by shared access signature.  This means that for subscribers to the bus there is a construct in the web config like this:

```
<sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManagerSharedAccessKey" key="somesecretcharacters=" />
```

The problem with this is that the key is visible.

Everything else on site is secured by Windows security. Is it possible to secure an on premise service bus so that only clients belonging to particular AD groups, or specific AD service accounts can gain access to it?